# Preventing Parent Android App to Look at the Webview Data

Tags: android, security, webview

- Below is logical view of the interaction with Android
  [image: Logical View of interactions]

Questions ?

- Can i prevent 3rd Party App ( parent app ) to directly hit Regulated Entity URL
- Any hard coding like URLs etc that can be prevented to read from Parent App.
- I want to encrypt event data that is transmitted between iframe and `Acme Company SDK` - if i use AES 256 - the key is readable by Parent App
- Suggestions on security Mechanism